# Template equivalent of #var in macro

Tags: c++, macros

In C++ macros you can use `#var` to get the literal string of the argument passed:

```
#define PRINT_SIZE(type)                                                       \
    (std::cout << sizeof(type) << " " << #type << std::endl)
```

Using this macro, I can write a very simple program which will give me the lengths of specific types on my machine:

```
PRINT_SIZE(bool);
PRINT_SIZE(char);
…
```

This does work but I would like to use C++ templates instead. Obtaining the size is easy with the following template function:

```
template <typename T>
void print_size() {
    std::cout << sizeof(T) << std::endl;
}
```

I can call this function with any type and it will output the size:

```
print_size<bool>();
print_size<char>();
…
```

Is there any way I could get a literal `"bool"` from this anywhere such that the output would be as nice as the one with macros?

Comment: typeid(type).name() using RTTI, I've never tried this though? https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/RTTI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can sortof be done using RTTI (runtime type inference) using typeid:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
void print_size() {
        T a;
        std::cout << typeid(a).name() << ": " << sizeof(T) << std::endl;
}

int main(){

    print_size<bool>();
    print_size<char>();
    print_size<long>();

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
b: 1
c: 1
l: 8
```

Comment: I can also do `typeid(T).name()` and get the same result, so there seems to be no need to instantiate the type. The representation is somewhat cryptic (looks like `printf` format specifier) but better than nothing. Thanks!

Comment: Thats good to know. the wikibooks page says the representation is compiler dependant.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `typeid()` as in:

```
int i;
cout << typeid(i).name();    // Most likely will print int but g++ prints i
cout << typeid(int).name();  // Also most likely will print int but g++ prints i
```

Note that the name it returns depends on the compiler and may be some unusual form of the type. More information [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/name/).

**Edit:**

g++ (4.8) prints only the first letter of fundamental types. For user defined classes, it prints the number of characters in the name followed by the name. Ex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class myclass
{
    myclass() {}
};

class my
{
    my() {}
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << typeid(int).name() << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeid(bool).name() << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeid(myclass).name() << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeid(my).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
i
b
7myclass
2my
```

Comment: With GCC and Clang I get single letters. Which compiler did you try?

Comment: @MartinUeding I am using g++ 4.8.4 but actually I had never tried for fundamental types, but only for classes I defined. I just run a series of tests and g++ gives i,f,d, and b for `int`, `float`, `double` and `bool`. For the classes I define, however, it gives the full name, preceeded by the number of characters, e.g., `mytype` appears as `6mytype` and `mine` as `4mine`.